# Laravel/docker-compose/redis - Class 'Redis' not found

Tags: php, laravel, redis, docker-compose, laravel-6.2

This project was set up by another team and I'm unable to get passed this one error. Using PHP 7.2 and Laravel 6.2. My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
redis:
    image: redis
    command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes","--requirepass","Redis.123"]
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data
    container_name: redis-master
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

and `database.php`:

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
        ],

    ]
```

The container is up and running and "Ready to accept connections". This error is in my stack trace if I attempt to hit the base url or any endpoints. I have aliased redis in `app.php`: `'RedisManager' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,` as others have recommended. Can anyone see anything obvious that is missing or could cause this? Predis is installed in the `composer.json`: `"predis/predis": "^1.1",`, but not set in the config. If I changed phpredis to predis I get the error `development.ERROR:`SELECT`failed: NOAUTH Authentication required. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]`.

Answer (score 2):

The error you get when you set to `phpredis`, it is most likely related to phpredis extension. You need to install this extension if you want to use `phpredis` client.

The error you get when you set it to `predis` is totally different. It is authentication error because you didn't set password. In your `.env` file, append this

```
REDIS_PASSWORD=Redis.123
```

Then `artisan config:clear`, it could do the work.

Comment: I'm using envkey for my .env and the REDIS_PASSWORD in there is null, so I'm guessing phpredis was intended. I checked and I have redis in my php.ini correctly: `php -r "if (new Redis() == true){ echo \"\r\n OK \r\n\"; }"` returns OK and php -i | grep Redis looks good as well: `Redis Support => enabled
Redis Version => 5.2.2
Redis Sentinel Version => 0.1`. I also have `extension="redis.so"` at the top of my php7.2.ini and have restarted php7.2 with `brew services restart php@7.2`.

Comment: what happens if you set `phpredis` as `REDIS_CLIENT` with the set password as i offered in the answer ? Do you get any error or it works ? @MattLarson

Comment: I ended up doing a full reboot and phpredis was working, but ended up needing the REDIS_PASSWORD anyway, so added that to envkey. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In `.end` file, please put `REDIS_HOST=redis-master` which is your redis container name.